как при выполнении программы определяется тип считываемых данных?
возможно, вопрос сформулирован некорректно, но поверьте, мне трудно как-то правильно это сделать и если б я мог, то обязательно сформулировал бы почётче.
попытаюсь раскрыть суть вопроса. в общем если смотреть по таблице аски, то символ 3 будет кодироваться числом 32 в 16ричке, что запишется определённым двоичным кодом в памяти. но кроме символа 3 я могу записать число типа unsigned int 50, который будет иметь такой же двоичный код. да, размер данных отличается, но как процессор понимает, хотим мы получить инт или чар, если двоичный код у них одинаков?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Никак не понимает, процессору абсолютно пофиг — какие команды вы ему пошлёте, то он и выполнит, даже если это не будет иметь никакого смысла

Собственно, в контексте сишечки и символов можно придумать такой бессмысленный пример, который интерпретирует число как строку и вполне успешно печатает её int i = 4609111; printf("%s\n", (char*)&i);

Тип данных понимает компилятор, который производит нужные для обработки именно этого типа данных команды процессора. Это происходит до начала выполнения программы. Во время ее исполнения никто про типы данных уже понятия не имеет.

Процессор никак не определяет. Для каких-то операций (например, целочисленного сложения или вычитания) вообще нет разницы, знаковое число или нет. Там где имеет значение - просто компилятор формирует машинный код, подразумевающий, что число какого-то типа (например, div/idiv, mul/imul).
